# Copying address of one array into another

Tags: java, arrays, copying

```
public class zeroCheck {
    
    int a[]={2,3,4};
    int c[]={5,6,7};

    void addMore(int arr[])
    {
        int another[] = new int[6];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, another, 0, 3);
        System.arraycopy(c, 0, another, 3, 3);
         
        for(int x:another)
        {
            System.out.print(x + "\t");
        }
        // prints 2 3 4 5 6 7 0

        // Trying to copy address of another array into the original
        arr = another;

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        zeroCheck o=new zeroCheck();
        // System.out.println(o.a.length);

        int b[] = new int[6];
        o.addMore(b);
            
        for(int x:b)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        // prints 0 0 0 0 0 
        
    }
    
}
```

Here I was trying to copy the address of `another` into the parameter, but it looks like it didn't affect the original array. I speculate an arrayname contains the address, so it should be pass by reference meaning any change in the `addMore` method will reflect in the `main`. So, the array `b[]` should be the same as `another[]`.

I ran the code and the output appears to be like this:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 0
0
0
0
0
0
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the `int arr[]` syntax of declaring arrays is considered a historic quirk of the Java syntax, and not something you should use. Please declare arrays as `int[] arr` instead, as that is the generally accepted syntax.

Comment: There is no such thing as an address in Java.